# Facing problem in displaying service data into grid

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-ui

I am working on Angular project where I am facing problem in displaying data
Facing problem in **displaying data** coming from service **into  three  rows  dynamically** 
**just like bootstrap grid view** 
eg:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
     <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
```

I am putting my html code below -

```
                <div class="container" *ngFor="let match of upcommingMatch; let i = index">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="match_section">
                        <h3>{{match.tournamentName}}</h3>
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="country_image">
                                <img src="{{match.team1PhotoUrl}}"/>
                              </div>
                              <p class="country_name">{{match.team1Name}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="vs">
                                <img src="../../assets/imgs/vs.png"/>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="country_image">
                                <img src="{{match.team1PhotoUrl}}" />
                              </div>
                              <p class="country_name">{{match.team2Name}}</p>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <p class="time">67h  59m  13s</p>
                          <a>Join</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

more Info : I am using Angular Material design

> **I want** : to display data in below Image

[image]

> **But my current data** is displayed like this -:

[image] (.html part)

Comment: whts the problem you facing?

Comment: Please add essential parts of your code, create demo if you can

Comment: @Justcode I have modified please see maybe it will be more clear now

Comment: @umesh99 I have modified please see maybe it will be more clear now

Answer (score 0):

You're adding divs with a grid class of `col-md-4` one after another, so they're (quite rightly) rendering in 3 columns, side by side. In order to have a column of data centered, but still within the size you want, you need to offset the columns so bootstrap can derive the positioning correctly.

```
...
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="country_image">
        <img src="{{match.team1PhotoUrl}}"/>
    </div>
    <p class="country_name">{{match.team1Name}}</p>
</div>
...
```

The addition here being `col-md-offset-4`... i.e give me a column 4 grid squares wide, but offset it by 4 grid squares from the left. A bootstrap row must be made up of columns 12 grid squares wide:

**Offset** 4 + **Content** 4 + **Remaining Space** 4 === 12.

Otherwise the columns float side-by-side.

Comment: I implementrd with col-md-offset-4 and also with col-md-offset-6 
but it didn't worked , data is still coming in one row

example -:  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-offset-6">
                              <mat-grid-tile>
                                  <div class="match_section">

Comment: You can't just use `col-md-offset-6`, that's just the offset value, you still need to tell it what the actual column width would be, so you need **both** `col-md-6` **and** `col-md-offset-6`

Comment: Your example, corrected: `<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1"> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6"> <mat-grid-tile> <div class="match_section">`

Comment: ...although, that offset will float the 6 grid squares all the way to the right. To center it, it should be `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`.